# Quartz Scheduler and RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, quartz-scheduler

Is there a way to kick off a job in Quartz based on a message arriving from RabbitMQ and making the contents of the message available for the job?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know RabbitMQ, but here is a basic code:

```
QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
String message = new String(delivery.getBody());
```

You schedule your job like this:

```
JobDetail job1 = newJob(MessageJob.class)
    .usingJobData("message", message)
    .build();

Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
    .startNow()
    .build();
```

And inside `MessageJob` you retrieve it:

```
public class MessageJob implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(final JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        final String message = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().getString("message");
        //...
    }
```

Note that you cannot "*kick off*" a job, you can only schedule it to run some time in the future (in the example it'll run as soon as possible - `startNow()`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not... You can subscribe to a RabbitMQ queue and when a message arrives you can do whatever, including fire a Quartz.NET job.